# How do we capture the ManualStepTest Description and Expected Result text box values in groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have captured the `xml` & `Jdbc` based request and response through `groovyscript` in the soap `ui` tool.

But I am not able to read the manual step notes (description/expected message).

Using below code I can reach the manual test step but not sure about reading values from the text box.

```
if(testStep.config.type=="manualTestStep")
{ log.info "this is manual request"}
```

so can some one give your idea on this.Thanks in advance.
adding screen shot for reference[currently the outputlog.info is displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98FHJ.jpg)

Response [DuringTestExecution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EWJ2.jpg) of Manual Steps

Comment: Can you share the box image you are talking about ? Where do we have (description/expected message) in soapui ?

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for your reply, i don't see any option to attach any screen shot /image to this comment section but i will tell you the steps for that. in the soap ui -> after opening some project-> go to test cases-> right click->insert step->choose "Manual test Step "(last option from the list)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @Nagoor. Please find the answer and if it helps you may upvote and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below command is to get the **description** of **manual Step** in **soapui**

```
def desdcriptionOfManualTestStep=testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Manual").description
log.info desdcriptionOfManualTestStep
```

Also you can use below code for Description of manual step

```
def desdcriptionOfManualTestStep=testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Manual").getDescription()
log.info desdcriptionOfManualTestStep
```

The below command can help you getting the **expected result**

```
def expectedResult = context.expand( '${Manual#ExpectedResult}' )
log.info expectedResult
```

Here is the manual step

[image]

Here are the logs

[image]

Comment: Using { def desdcriptionOfManualTestStep=testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Verify Manual").description
log.info desdcriptionOfManualTestStep } it is reading the Description text box text values alone  but it is not returning the test case property values , can you check my screen shot for more detail@gaurav

Comment: I really doubt if that is possible. I.e. Reading values in description part of manual step.. Its working in expected Result though

Comment: yes that is working during the test case execution, like if we add the test case level property values the values are showing on the screen but when we use the groovy to capture the same , but unfortunately it is not fetching the values.

Comment: No what i am saying is in the Descirption box of Manual step.. Groovy script syntax not working.. But its working in expected result and other places

Comment: Can you refer my second screen shot which clearly show that groovy script coding were  working in the Manual step text boxes@Gaurav khurana

Comment: So you have shown the positive case where its working, So when its not working ?

Comment: i am saying that the values were showing properly while running the manual steps but i am not able to read the same through groovy using getTestStepByName.description class

Comment: Can you give this a try .getDescription()   def desdcriptionOfManualTestStep=testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Manual").getDescription()
log.info desdcriptionOfManualTestStep

Comment: Yeah i have tried now and it is also returning the same behavior like getTestStepByName.description class but anyhow Really thanks a lot for your response ,